# Rotation of a rigid body within another orbiting body

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

I would like to understand the physical behaviour of the following rotating sytstem. 
[image: Rotating system]

There are 3 rigid bodies (1 is blue, 2 are red). We assume that there is no friction between the blu body and the red bodies, i.e. no friction along the dashed line.

The blue body is rotated clockwise with constant angular velocity with respect to its center of mass (point O in the figure).

What kind of motion do the red cylinders exhibit with respect to

1. The lab's frame?
2. A frame rotating as the blue body?

Comment: since there is no friction, the  only possible way how the blue body can exert forces on red bodies is by radial force. Therefore in lab's frame the red bodies have fixed orientation in space

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very helpful comment. Can you please answer also point number 2? You can also consider writing an actual answer instead of a comment.

Comment: i think having the answer for the first question is enaugh for getting the answer to the second simply by grabbing two objects and trying it out with your hands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Lab Frame

You have posited the system is *began* with a rotational rate $\omega$. In this state, only a radial force is required to satisfy the constraints of the blue object.  With only a radial force and an initial tangential velocity, the motion of the CM of the red objects is **uniform circular motion**.

The red objects would not change their orientation in the lab frame, due to the lack of friction and due to the initial conditions.  For instance, if you painted an arrow on each red object, and made both arrows parallel, they would remain parallel through the rotational motion.

#### Rotating Frame

In a frame attached to the blue object, the motion of the red objects would be **uniform rotational motion about their centers**.  Again, this falls from the fact that the system was began in an initial state of uniform circular motion.  If we take the same parallel arrows as before, then from the rotating frame the arrows rotate in the *opposite* direction but at the same rate $\omega$.

Comment: Curious note: the arrows in the rotating frame are *still* always parallel.